# Wordpress - locally installed on raspberry pi not recognizing upgraded php version

Tags: php, wordpress

I've updated my version of PHP to 7.0

> pi@raspberrypi:~ $ php -version
>   PHP 7.0.33-0+deb9u6 (cli) (built: Oct 24 2019 18:50:20) ( NTS )

If I display my version in WordPress it's still pointing to the old version

> PHP Version: 5.6.40-0+deb8u7

tried update Wordpress again still points to version 5.6

Comment: regardless of wp - what does `phpinfo()` say ( place it in same wp directory )

Comment: php-cli is different to php used by the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

I also was looking for the answer on this question. I had php5.6 installed, when I started with Wordpress on my pi. I first upgraded jessie to stretch on raspbian and after that to buster (debian 10). That worked and my php-version under raspbian was 7.3 . However Wordpress (apache2) still had the old version installed.

Then I stumbled on this site: https://tecadmin.net/switch-between-multiple-php-version-on-debian/. And that worked for me.

```
# a2dismod php5 php7.1 php7.0
# a2enmod php7.3
# systemctl restart apache2
```

That was all to it...